# How to compare two time in PHP accurately?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

time() function in PHP used to get current time.But there's a problem!
Suppose we get the current time 12:05 AM (EST) using this function, then if i compare this time with another time(For example,10:50 AM),obviously PHP will consider that the timestamp of 10:50 AM is greater than 12:05 AM)..but actually it's wrong!12:05 is basically 00:05 AM...!!!
I don't know how to compare times like this accurately,any help would be appreciated.

I'm using this block of code to compare those two times...

```
$current_time = time(); //suppose current time is 12:15 AM(returned by time() func)
$time1 = '1:30 AM';
$draw_time = strtotime($time1);
if($current_time < $draw_time1) {
   echo 'Perfectos!';
}
```

Comment: _PHP will consider that the timestamp of 10:50 AM is greater than 12:05 AM)..but actually it's wrong_ It's right if it's on the same day.

Comment: _12:05 AM (EST)_ So are you aware that EST is a timezone?

Comment: @nice_dev apparently it's correct...but 12:05 AM means 0:05AM,isn't it?if timestamp of 12:05 is greater than 10:50 AM means it should be 12:05 PM,not AM

Comment: There is a difference between the same day and the next day!

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: 7th Nov 12:05 AM = 7th Nov 00:05 AM which is obviously smaller than 7th Nov 10:50 AM. Which is why 10:50 AM > 00:005 AM. Had it been, 7th Nov 10:50 AM and 8th Nov 00:05 AM, then you argument would have been correct, but then PHP would have also returned a correct result.

Comment: @nice_dev yes,i got that..but then how can i compate those two properly!The main thing is i have check if user proceed with time which is already over,like i'm not allowed to proceed with time which is already over for that day

Comment: In that case, you might want to ask a more concrete question by making a new post with input, the output you got and with you expect to get(which in Stackoverflow terms we call as minimum reproducible example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $current_time = time();
    $time1 = date('d.m.Y') . ' 11:42 AM';
    $draw_time = strtotime($time1);
    echo ($draw_time) . " " . $current_time . "\r\n";
    if ($current_time < $draw_time) {
        echo 'True';
    } else {
        echo 'False';
    }
```

You can try this way
Your code is incorrect , bacause you get first variable for only hour and second variable for whole time

Comment: yes,you're correct but if we pass any parameter thorugh strtotime(),it'll give timestamp of that string with current date/time anyway..isn't it?thanks for help though